# Convert Single Row To Single Column Using Pivot/unpivot In Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, data-analysis, unpivot

I have a table with a single row as below:

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| (Col1)| (Col2)| (Col3)| (Col4)| (Col5)|
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| Data1 | Data2 | Data3 | Data4 | Data5 |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

What I want to do seems very simple, but I am not able to find any examples of it anywhere. All I want is to convert the above row into a single column like so:

```
+-------------+
|(Column Name)|
+-------------+
|Data1        |
+-------------+
|Data2        |
+-------------+
|Data3        |
+-------------+
|Data4        |
+-------------+
|Data5        |
+-------------+
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Does/will your table always have only a single record in it?  If it has more than 1 row, can you show us what that would look like?

Comment: See about UNOIN.

Comment: The answer depends on what RDBMS you are **really** using. Don't tag multiple RDBMS, just the one you are really using. `UNPIVOT` isn't supported in MySQL, as far as I am aware, it's a T-SQL operator.

Comment: Either `UNPIVOT` or `CROSS APPLY (VALUES(col1),(col2...`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen this is result set of UNOIN query which is always expected to have single row with multiple columns.

Comment: @Strawberry yes, i did achieve expected result set using union, but using using union  4 or 5 times on one query rather seems odd/desperate approach to reach goal.

Comment: Thanks @Charlieface, I would really appreciate if you could give example for UNPIVOT.

Comment: Sure - but that's a fault of your data model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using `apply`:

```
select v.col
from t cross apply
     (values (col1), (col2), (col3), (col4), (col5)) v(col);
```

I strongly recommend `apply` over `unpivot`.  However, they are not 100% equivalent, because `unpivot` filters out `NULL` values.